# How do I count only cells with data in aws quicksight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I need help to count only cells with data in QuickSight.

eg: we have:

```
    message(field name)
    abcde%
    
    fghijk123
    
    http error 411


    testing number 235
```

I need the syntax in QuickSight for counting the number of cells with data in the above.
Example answer is 4.
I tried using 'count' but it didn't work.

Please help with this.